# CMake imported library rpath

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, ld

I have an `IMPORTED` `SHARED` library for and I'm linking with it via `target_link_libraries` (the library has `IMPORTED_LOCATION` set).

But then after installation in `ldd` output I see smth like:

`path/on-dev-machine/to/libxxx.so => not found`

instead of just

`libxxx.so => path/on-testing-machine/to/libxxx.so`

Why is that / how do I fix it? I'm adding lib paths to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`

Sample code:

```
include(GNUInstallDirs)

function(add_and_install_lib lib_name location external_dep)
    if(${location} MATCHES ".*\\.so")
        add_library(${lib_name} SHARED IMPORTED) # MODULE treated as shared
    else()
        add_library(${lib_name} STATIC IMPORTED)
    endif()

    set_property(TARGET ${lib_name} PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${location})

    add_dependencies(${lib_name} ${external_dep})
endfunction()


set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}") # this doesn't seem to help
```

Comment: *IMPORTED_LOCATION* works only at build stage. For make the library searchable at runtime, see [CMake RPATH handling](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling).

Comment: @Tsyvarev `set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}")` doesn't seem to help, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't either, I guess the problem that somehow there's a full path to lib instead of the lib file itself (on the left of `=>` of `ldd`). Do you know why this can be?

Comment: Show CMake code. It is hard to tell something about paths correctness without the code.

Comment: @Tsyvarev here you are

Comment: The code you show doesn't create executable, doesn't link it with external library, doesn't install it. Instead, it defines a function with location of the external library as a parameter, and one can only guess which value it has. Please, provide [mcve]. Also, you talk about *path-on-dev-machine* and *path-on-testing-machine*. Does this mean that you install the executable on the "dev" machine, and then copy it to the "testing" one?

Comment: Could you set  **RPATH** above **add_library**, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone cares, it was the `IMPORTED_NO_SONAME` property (absence of it set to `TRUE`) of each imported lib that forced the full path to be taken.

Also `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH` and `CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH` are useful in my opinion to make sure you have clean runtime paths (not straightly related to the question but still).